# How do I improve our setup of multiple domains: tracking shared goals and settings, but separate reports

Tags: google-analytics

We have a growing number of domains (for each country we operate in) that all have identical functionality and should have the same kind of goals, reports etc in Google Analytics. (but each domain be tracked individually, no data aggregation over all domains)

Our current setup is as follows

1. **property**: domain.nl

   - **view**: domain.nl

     - settings, goals for this domain configured manually
2. **property**: domain.de

   - **view**: domain.de

     - settings, goals for this domain configured manually
3. **property**: ...

This is terrible;
The amount of work grows with each domain added. When we want to configure a new goal, we have to add it to each view separately. And we have different UA- tracking codes for each domain. This also makes it impossible to do Google Optimize A/B tests among all domains combined, since Google Optimize requires goals of a single view.

What is the perfect way to set this up?

**What I have tried:**
I today tried to solve our puzzle by creating a single property and make a view for each domain within that property. I realized this still does not solve our problem, since the goals are defined on the view-level. Also, I didn't manage to correctly segment each domains' traffic into each view. Specifying the "default domain" in the view settings was not enough, and the filtering section in the view settings seems to be made for filtering outgoing traffic (?)

Which makes me think that we should either cluster everything in a single view and configure the view to segment all reporting per domain (is this possible, and does this give easy to interpret output?)

Or, there is a better standard way of doing this which I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single view (a single property) and then **segment** with the domain. Be careful that if the traffic is high and you don't have Google 360 ​​you can easily reach the sampling thresholds: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

You can also **share a goal** to another view. Tick your Goal in Administration View, the click on share to obtain a link, go to that link and apply the goal to the view you want: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en

[image]